# How draw horizontal grid in matplotlib when hidden yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, grid

For visualization reasons, I removed the yaxis labels, however I want to keep the horizontal grid. How can I do it?

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0,23])
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.grid()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to remove just the labels or also the tick marks.

In any case, the line

```
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False) #I am assuming it is y not x
```

can be removed. We are not hiding the axis but just the tick labels.

For that, add:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
```

This gives:

[image]

If you also want to remove the tick marks/lines, you can further add:

```
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(left=False)
```

So:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_ylim([0,23])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter()) # to remove the labels
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(left=False) # to remove the tick marks
ax.yaxis.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]